# Howto Design "hierarchical data" for a Learning Management System(LMS) 

Tags: mysql, django, design-patterns, database-design

I'm supposed to design a Learning Management System (LMS), from scratch.
In regards to the "Course" entity, I have 3 levels of info (Course, Topic, Sub_Topic). Imagine it like a tree.
Now, which of these methods (or any better way?) is more useful?

1- Using "Adjacency List Model" (http://www.sqlsummit.com/AdjacencyList.htm) or

2- using 3 Tables , each for one of these levels, and join them for getting records?

Please bear in mind that each of these levels have "separate attributes" and have connections with "Quizes" as well. So there are some interaction among each of these fields with "Quiz entity" as well ..

P.S. System will be implemented in Django and MySQL ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the tree possesses clearly separated levels, each holding distinct *kind* of data, I'd go with the "3 tables" approach.

You'd need JOINs either way, but this way you can easily enforce correct referential integrity (so for example, a course can contain topic but not the other way around). This also naturally avoids cycles.

I'm not sure how "Quiz entity" factors in all this. Care to provide more info?

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. I'm thinking on making two type of quizzes : "Multiple-choice" and "Normal" Questions. Quizzes can be asked from any level, or they can be selected in multiple levels at the same time .. So maybe this factor also reinforces the 3 tables design as well